# How to replace ' character in coldfusion

Tags: replace, coldfusion

That's the problem I am having as the system doesn't let me do this kind of replacement as it's used to delimitate the string to replace.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without seeing any code whatsoever, it's going to be hard to know how to help.

Comment: Why do you need to do that, out of curiosity? (I ask because there are a lot of bad reasons to try to replace that character.)

Comment: I am trying to web parse some information from the source of a website. And the source appears to be for example:  content='40.4241216' itemprop='latitude', and those ' there doesn't let me catch the information I require properly.

Comment: What are you trying and how are the quotes thwarting your efforts?

Comment: Replace(string, "'", "", "all");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you string is escaped so that coldusion is not finding the characters you want to replace.

You can try something like

```
<cfset StrUtils = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils") />
<cfset result = Replace( StrUtils.unescapeHTML( your_str ), "'", "*", "ALL") />
```